# How to take each element out of an array and make each element a key in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a nested array of strings, within an object, within an array. I am trying to pull out the nested strings and place each element as a key in an object and all of the values of each key would be set to 0 without hardcoding anything

```
const groups = [{name: group1, values: ['value1']},{name: group2, values: ['value2', 'value'}]
```

I am trying to get the `'value1'`, `'value2'`, and `'value3'`, and place them into an object as a key - so, it should look like this:

```
const obj = {'value1': 0,'value2': 0,'value3': 0,}
```

I have this which gives me an array of the values, but I'm not sure how to take them out of that array and put them as keys in an object.

```
const allGroups = groups.flatMap(({ values }) => values,);
```

Comment: Where does `value3` come from? The original array has values `value1, value2, value`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` loop and your object was in a wrong format

```js
const groups = [{name: 'group1', values: ['value1']},{name:' group2', values: ['value2', 'value3']}]
var obj={};
groups.forEach(e=>{
e.values.forEach(x=>obj[x]=0)
})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const groups = [{name: 'group1', values: ['value1']},{name: 'group2', values: ['value2', 'value3']}]

const allGroups = Object.fromEntries(groups.flatMap(({
  values
}) => values.map(v => [v, 0])))

console.log(allGroups)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, flatMap should give you a falttened array containing values. After that you just need to use [Array's reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create the object.

Here how you can do it, in kind-of functional way:

```js
const groups = [
  { name: 'group1', values: ['value1'] },
  { name: 'group2', values: ['value2', 'value3'] }
];
let values = groups
  .flatMap(group => group.values)
  .reduce((acc, values) => {
    acc[values] = 0;
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce()` to iterate through each object with the goal of creating a single result. Within the iteration you'd add each entry in `values` to the output object as a key, with value `0`.

```js
const groups = [{name: 'group1', values: ['value1']},{name: 'group2', values: ['value2', 'value']}];
const result = groups.reduce((out,obj) => (obj.values.forEach(v => out[v]=0), out),{});
console.log(result);
```